# RegExp on YYYY-MM-DD with variable input

Tags: regex

I'm using this for `regexp` for valid `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY-M-D`:

```
^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

I would like to be able to also validate for the following combinations as valid:

```
YYYY-MM
YYYY-M
YYYY
```

So either `DD`/`D` only or `DD`/`D`and `MM`/`M` can be left out.

Comment: Try `^\d{4}(?:-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?)?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/Uf0Yyo/1

Comment: If you want different branches, why not write them as such? `^(\d{4}|\d{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[012])|\d{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))$` Should do the trick, even if it is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex expression

```
^\d{4}(?:-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?)?$
```

as also said by [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707602/regexp-on-yyyy-mm-dd-with-variable-input#comment98096079_55707602) in the comment section